# Transform attributes to sub elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert attributes to sub elements, i.e. turn the following:

```
<employees companyid="101">
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>pradeep</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>som</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Javed</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
</employees>
```

I want to transform in this way

```
<employees>
    <record>

        <id>1</id>
        <name>pradeep</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>som</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Javed</name>
        <designation>softeng</designation>
    </record>
</employees>
```

It's not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So we should spot the differences between the two? Do I get a chocolate if I find them all?

Comment: Please share your attempts. The two applicable closing criteria for this question read: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance." and
"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Comment: Is your expected output correct, by the way? There is an "companyid" attribute in your input sample, but it does not appear in your output. As you mention about turning attributes into sub-elements it suggests something has gone walk-about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you need the `<companyid>` element on each `<record>` level. You can use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <companyid><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::employees/@companyid"/></companyid>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to let it appear on the first `<record>` element you can change `<xsl:template match="record">` to `<xsl:template match="record[1]">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <employees>
            <xsl:copy-of select="employees/*"/> 
        </employees>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming that your output is correct and that you only want to remove the companyid attribute.

Comment: We can all guess what he wants, because the output is not correct diplayed, but he says "just trying to convert attributes to sub elements"